# Using turbo C on windows 7

Tags: c, windows, dos, virtualization, turbo-c

I am using windows 7 OS. My younger bro wants to use the (ancient :P) turbo C on the same machine.

Is there any way using which without installing XP, I can run turbo C with full screen resolution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is [dosbox](http://www.dosbox.com) an option ?

Comment: Did you try running the program in XP mode, which is an option in windows 7

Comment: Why don't you tell your brother to just use gcc?

Answer (score 2):

you can use Dosbox for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a Professional or higher-grade Windows7, you can also use the Windows XP Mode (the Virtual PC tool, not just the "Run as" option).

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode

Comment: @Woot4Moo: didn't know which one you were talking about, so I added this reply.

Answer (score 0):

**use DOSBOX for this purpose**
pls click the link [Download Fullscreen Turbo C++ For Windows 7, Vista and XP](http://www.megaleecher.net/sites/default/files/Turbo_C++_for_Windows.zip)

install it. To make the the compiler launch in full-screen just edit the shortcut (on desktop by right-click -> properties) and change the "Run" option to "Maximized"

Answer (score 0):

Use dosbox

For complete details check

[Dosbox in windows 7](http://coder.gairainfotech.com/2014/02/how-to-run-turbo-c-in-windows7-or-windows-8/)

Answer (score -2):

download "TurboC++ FOr WIndows 7"

Comment: please add reason and more detail explanation to your answer, not just opinion

Comment: Also this has already been suggested in [Bibin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15178058/2227743)